# Trouble understanding break vs else statements with nested loops

Tags: python

I'm practicing python and one of the coding tasks assigned was to create a function that looks through a list and ignores numbers that occur between a 6 and a 9 and returns the sum of all other values.

Edit: this does not mean to add numbers whose values are less than 6 or greater than 9. It means to add all numbers of any value, but to ignore any numbers that come after a 6, until a 9 is seen. Symbolically if i means include and x means exclude, the code should return all the values marked as i:

`[i,i...6, x,x,...,9,i,i...,6,x,x,...]`

In other words, 6 turns off adding and if adding is off, 9 turns it back on.

Note that a 9 with no preceding 6 is just a number and will be added.

For example if I have a list:

```
[4,5,6,7,8,9,9]
```

the output should be:

```
8 <---(4+5+9)
```

The solution is provided but I'm having trouble understanding the code. I don't understand the purpose of the break statements in the code. The solution provided is as follows:

```
def summer_69(*arr):
total = 0
add = True

for num in arr:
    while add == True:
        if num!=6:
            total = total + num
            break
        else:
            add = False
    while add == False:
        if num !=9:
            break
        else:
            add = True
            break
return total
```

I'm really confused how the break statements help with the code. Particularly, I'm confused why the first 'break' is needed when there is already an 'else'.

The second break confuses me as well.

I understand that 'break' statements stop a loop and go onto the next loop.

My interpretation of the code so is 'if the number does not equal to 6 then total = total + num, if it does equal 6 then the loop is broken and if it is broken, add changes to False'.

I'm not sure if that interpretation is correct or not.

I was wondering how seasoned Python coders interpret 'breaks' vs 'else'.

Comment: It's probably important to mention that this code doesn't work and or solve the problem. Are you looking to have an explanation on broken / non functioning code?

Comment: As a side note, the 'solution' you've been given is really poorly written. Using while loops that can never execute more than once is a rather... strange idea. Using `if` here would be much clearer.

Comment: @JerryM. I think there was supposed to be a *arr in the array so it can take in multiple arguments

Comment: This code is a well-known classic pattern from days of yore. It does what it is supposed to do. Those who think otherwise have just misunderstood what it is supposed to do. I've added an edit to improve clarity about the intent of the code.

Answer (score 0):

`break` will exit whatever loop the statement is in. It's useful for many things, but often it's used to "short-circuit" the loop. If we know that the rest of the loop is irrelevant after some condition is met, then it's just wasted resources to keep looping through.

Comment: If you exit a while loop, do you go onto the next loop below or the loop above?

Comment: It will only break out of whatever loop it's in. If it's in a nested loop, then the outer loop will continue looping. If it's not in a nested loop, then the code with continue from where the while loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

The break statement allow you to leave the while loop, but the if else statement allow you to stay in loop, until the condition of the while loop change or a break statement is in the action into the while loop

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky way to handle program flow with a toggle nested in conditional loops.

It's a little hard to follow, but it is a well-known classic pattern.

Initially ADD == True, so if we start with a number that is not 6 (as in your example), the algorithm adds the number & breaks out of the first while loop. When it breaks, the next statement executed will be the line `while add == False`

At this point ADD == TRUE so the second while loop will not be entered. The next statement executed will be `for num in arr` (the outermost loop).

The outer FOR loop will go again and this process will repeat.

When you encounter a 6, the number will not be added and the break will not occur. The program will execute the `else` clause, setting ADD = FALSE.
After the `else` clause, execution continues with statement `while add == false`. Since ADD == FALSE at this point, the second while loop will be entered.

From now on ADD will be FALSE so the first While loop will not be entered and numbers will not be added. Instead, the condition for the second while loop will be evaluated for each number. As long as numbers are not equal to 9, the second while loop will not be entered.

When you encounter a 9, you will enter the second while loop, switch ADD back to TRUE, and break out of the while loop.

The first 9 comes after a 6 (ADD is FALSE) so it just toggles ADD from FALSE to TRUE and the number 9 doesn't get added.

When the NEXT 9 is encountered, ADD is TRUE and the number is not 6, so the first while loop will be entered and the number 9 will get added.

This is a classic pattern that used to be used in assembly language code perhaps 40 years ago. As written, the IF statements toggle a state variable. The state variable is turned on when the start condition is met, and turned off when a stop condition is met. The while loops ensure that the toggle can only be turned ON when it was OFF and vice versa, and provide places to put in different handling when the state is ON vs when it is OFF. This pattern brings certain efficiencies that are completely irrelevant in modern high-level languages.

There are better ways to do this in all modern languages, but as an exercise in following tricky program flow it's quite good :)

Comment: Right. The indents were messed up during my copy and paste. I've edited it, Any thoughts?

Comment: I explained exactly what is happening and why it's being done that way. The while loops act as toggles to turn addition ON or OFF. One fires when you get to 6 to turn addition OFF, and if addition is off then the other fires when you get to 9 to turn addition back ON. Everything else gets added. The logic is fine and the code works as intended, and I explained how it works -- the bad indentation didn't confuse me. Did my explanation (and this comment) answer your question?  If so, please accept the answer. Otherwise, step through the code yourself as if you were the processor and you'll get it

Answer (score 0):

The solution you've provided is extremely convoluted and hard to understand.

A much better solution is:

```
  total = 0
    for num in arr_2:
        if(num >= 6 and num <=9):
            continue
        total += num
```

Or a more pythonic way:

```
 filtered_arr = filter(lambda x: x <6 or x > 9, arr_2)
 total = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, arr)
```

Anyways, in your solution, the first break is absolutely redundant. The reason why there is a break there, is because when you've found a number that doesn't equal 6, you add it, and you get out of the while loop.

In other words, the solution should have used an if statement, instead of the while statement. The break is there to basically have the while loop execute once.

Because, if a number does equal 6, then add will be false, and the while loop will terminate. If a number does not equal 6, you get out of the while loop. So the while loop is pointless, and meant to be an if statement instead.

Comment: Look more closely: the first break is not redundant. I've explained the program flow in my answer. I agree that there are much better ways to do this, but your answers don't do what is asked: add numbers until a start marker is encountered (in this case a 6) and then ignore numbers until a stop marker (9) is encountered. We want to add numbers that are greater than 6 and less than 9 -- just not numbers that are POSITIONED between a 6 and a 9.

Comment: Huh? my code does exactly that. Add all the numbers less than 6 and greater than 9. Nothing to do with "positioned" between a 6 and a 9, whatever that means.

Comment: No, You've misunderstood the intent and function of OP's code. It's not intended to add together numbers whose VALUES are below 6 or above 9, it's intended to add together numbers (of any value) in a list, while skipping values that appear between a 6 and a subsequent 9. Notice that in the expected output the first 9 is suppressed, but the second 9 is included? That's because the second one is outside the toggle markers. The logic of the code is classic and quite clear.  Read it closely and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Craig.Feied i keep re-reading OP's question, and I can't see how you deduce that the question is asking anything other than finding the sum of numbers below 6 and above 9 in a given list. To rephrase OP's question: "create a function that looks through a list and ignores numbers that occur between a 6 and a 9 and returns the sum of all other values." This clearly states to add numbers whose values are below 6 and above 9. We can't assume otherwise.